# How do I integrate SAML 2.0 in micronaut?

Tags: java, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api, micronaut

I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/standards/SAML/setting_up_a_saml_application_in_okta/) and completed setup, but I do not understand how do I use it in [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io)?
Please help me with the following?

1. Using `io.micronaut.context.env.Environment` I can load specific certificate, but is this loaded from `X.509 Certificate` text or I should create a publi.cert file from keytool?
   [image]
2. In okta developer console do I need to configure my application controller, so that this gets called on login, as I always get `405 Method Not Allowed` when I hit http://localhost:4200/xxx/api/sso/saml?

**update**

3. Also, how do I make use of the above "Setup Instructions" screenshot in my micronaut application, as it says SAML 2.0 is not configured in `https://developer.okta.com`? How should the AuthenticationController be called, is it a redirect in case of UnauthorizedError to this controller with relevant SAML Response and RelayState? How do I get this SAML Response?
   [image]

```
    @Controller('/xxx/api/sso')
    @Slf4j
    @CompileStatic
    class AuthenticationController {
        private final String DEFAULT_PERSONA = "DEFAULT"
        private static final Logger _authLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("AUTH_LOG");
        @Inject UserService userService

        @Value('${sso.issuer}')
        String SSO_SAML_ISSUER

        @Post('/saml')
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        HttpResponse<String> samlLogin(@Nullable @Body LinkedHashMap payload) {
        ...
```

Please help me understand integrating SAML 2.0 okta authentication with micronaut application.

How do I use the "Setup Instructions" in micronaut application?

Comment: You said you get a 405 "when I hit http://localhost:4200/xxx/api/sso/saml".  How are you hitting it?  If you are just putting that in a browser address bar I would not expect that to work because your `samlLogin` method looks like it is configured to accept `POST` requests.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I tried postman as well as from UI code

Comment: What HTTP request method are you using?  Your code says that only a `POST` should be allowed and the 405 suggests you are using something other than a `POST`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for pointing out, I tried it with POST in postman, it worked. I have updated my question asking for a bit more clarification.